# Automatically create a SharePoint survey on a regular basis

Tags: sharepoint, automation, survey

I've created a SharePoint survey that my department will be using to report some project updates on a weekly basis.  This survey is based on a template.

**Is there a way to have a new instance of the template automatically created on a weekly basis?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the list as a template. Use powershell to create the survey based on the custom template. This can be run as a timer job using an incremented variable to give each survey a unique name/url.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm new to PowerShell, but this sounds like a good direction to go in.